# REST API Design: Can I use parameters to change the response structure?

Tags: api, rest, web-services

I am trying to design a REST API that will return detailed information about an identifier that I pass in. For the sake of an example, I am passing in an identifier and returning information about a specific vehicle. The problem that I am facing is that there are many different kinds of vehicles, each with different unique properties. I am wondering if there is a way so that I can only return the relevant details with the REST API.

Currently I plan on having one endpoint `/vehicles` and passing in the identifier as a parameter.

My current request will consist of something like this `GET /vehicles?id=123456`

My current response structure will be something like this:

```
{
  "vehicleDetails" : {
    "color": "someColor",
    "make: "someMake",
    "model: "someModel",
    "year: "someYear",
    "carDetails": {
     // some unique car fields
    },
    "motorcycleDetails" : {
     // some unique motorcycle fields

    },
    "boatDetails" : {
     // some unique boat fields
    }
  }
}
```

As you can see, there are some fields that are common to all vehicle types, but there are also fields that are unique to a certain type of vehicle, for example boatDetails. As far as I understand, I will have to return the entire resource which will have many empty fields. For example, when I request information about a car, I will still have boat and motorcycle details returned as part of the JSON response, even though they will all be empty. My concern with this is that the response payloads will be rather large when only a small subset of the fields will actually be used by the consumer. Would it make sense to add another parameter to filter the fields that come back? Something like `/vehicles?id=123456&type=Car`? Then in my code I could manipulate the response structure based on the type parameter? I feel that this violates REST best practices. Any advice into how I could change the design of my API would be appreciated.

**Note: I cannot use GraphQL for this and would appreciate input about how I can improve this REST API design**

Answer (score 0):

Sure,query parameters (as well as matrix and path parameters) are fine from a REST standpoint. You'll end up with a unique URI that identifies a resource. Responses will be cacheable regardles what type of parameters you use. It is though questionable whether exposing the parameter as query parameter has any advantages over exposing it directly as path paramter, i.e. `/vehicles/12345` in that case.

What IMO is more important than the actual form of the URI is the representation format you return. The proposed response format bears the potential of being treated as [typed resource](http://soabits.blogspot.com/2012/04/restful-resources-are-not-typed.html) instead of utilizing a general, multi-purpose format and propper content-type negotiation. Think of HTML i.e. it defines the syntax and semantics of certain hyper-media controls you can use and any arbitrary Web client will be able to present it and operate on the response format. With custom formats, however, you will miss out on that feature.

If you only have one client, that moreover is under your control, the additional overhead you need to put in is probably not worth aiming for a REST environment in general, as it is easier to change the client once the server stuff changed. Though if you aim for a long-living environment that may be utilized by clients not under your control, this is for sure a thing to consider.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I use parameters to change the response structure?

Yes.

Example: https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/JPEG

Notice that -- even though the URI says JPEG, the server is actually returning a `text/html` document, and the browser knows that from the Content-Type header in the HTTP response.

Identifiers are semantically opaque, in the same way that variable names are.  We tend to choose spellings that make things easy for humans, but the machines don't care what spelling conventions we use.

So there's no constraint that says that `/vehicles?id=1` and `/vehicles?id=2` have to have the same "structure".

So you could have `application/prs.rbanders-car`, `application/prs.rbanders-boat` and `application/prs.rbanders-rocketship`, each with its own specific processing rules.

More likely, though, you'll want to piggyback on some other more common representation; so it's common to see a [structured syntax suffix](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6839): application/prs.rbanders-car+json`, etc.  Effectively, you are promising a json document, but with a more specific schema.

Of course, there's nothing stopping you from creating a `application/prs.rbanders-vehicle+json` schema, and then describing some fields as optional that will only appear if some condition is met.

Different options, different trade offs.

> I feel that this violates REST best practices.

Not really - the important ideas are to handle metadata in a standard way (so that general purpose components can understand what is going on) and to use common formats where it makes sense to do so (to leverage the libraries that are already available).